# i think i ruined my pc

Tags: android-x86

i tried to boot the andriod 86 on a partition on the E: drive ,
then i couldn't boot to my windows os anymore

i managed to get to the bios and putting my windows ssd to the top of the boot , it disapeard

now when i boot i eather get a black schreen, or android 86 uifg / boot manager

1. is there a way to fix to remove the boot manager
2. is there a way to boot from partition

Comment: First of all CALM DOWN! :) .. you didn't "ruin your pc".. you just hosed the bootloader.  The worst thing you will deal with is the loss of your windows partition data but that too is probably not going to happen.  Get yourself a windows 10 usb boot stick. Any windows 10 machine (other than yours) can make one for you using the media creation tool.  Boot to that stick and attempt a repair.  If that totally fails, use that same stick to reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reinstall windows as trying to load a different OS on the Drive with windows causes Software Conflicts.

You may need to wipe the drive before doing this as I have had the issue of other OS interfering with reloading windows back onto the hard drive and reformatting the partitions.

This can be done through the USB. Follow the links below and you will need at least a 16GB USB.

You will need a computer with Windows and you will need to install a windows 10 media creation tool found here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Then you will need to follow the steps for creating a USB directly below the download in the link above.

After that you need to find how to launch the boot menu on startup from the broken computer and plug the USB into the broken Computer.
This is different per computer manufacturer but it's usually F12,F2,F10 something like that.

From there you will select the USB that you just created and walk through the setup.

It is important that during the last stage of the setup when you see the partitions on the hard drive that you delete them and have window automatically reformat them.

If this does not work you will need to clean the drive via the CMD prompt prior to reinstalling windows instructions for this can be found here:

**** WARNING this step can have adverse side effects and I recommend Contacting Microsoft if you do not have extensive knowledge of OEM Software Codes ect.***

https://www.tomshardware.com/news/format-hard-drive-command-prompt,37632.html

If that does not work then there is a third option of just getting another SSD drive but the computer is not broken.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed it by opening a system partition with cmd naming it x and removing the boot grub and android folders